# Quartz.NET IOptionsSnapshot

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, quartz.net

The goal is to be able to change a setting in `appsettings.json` and have the job using this value automatically reflect the change and use the new value, but I just can't get it to work. Here's my latest attempt:

appsettings.json

```
"Settings": {
    "GameServerVersion": 15
},
```

Settings.cs

```
public class Settings
{
    public int GameServerVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        this.Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    private IJobManager JobManager { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddOptions();

        services.Configure<Settings>(this.Configuration.GetSection("Settings"));
        services.AddSingleton<ServersJob>();
        services.AddSingleton<JobFactory>();
        services.AddSingleton<IJobManager, JobManager>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

        app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
        app.UseLogger();
        app.UseMvc();

        this.JobManager = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IJobManager>();
        this.JobManager.StartAsync();
    }
```

JobManager.cs

```
public interface IJobManager
{
    void StartAsync();

    void StopAsync();
}


public class JobManager : IJobManager
{
    private static IScheduler scheduler;

    private readonly Settings settings;

    private readonly JobFactory jobFactory;

    public JobManager(IOptionsSnapshot<Settings> settingsAccessor, JobFactory jobFactory)
    {
        settings = settingsAccessor.Value;
        this.jobFactory = jobFactory;
    }

    public async void StartAsync()
    {
        StdSchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
        scheduler.JobFactory = this.jobFactory;

        IJobDetail serversJob = JobBuilder.Create<ServersJob>()
            .WithIdentity("serversJob", "MainGroup")
            .Build();

        ITrigger serversTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("serversTrigger", "MainGroup")
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(10).RepeatForever())
            .ForJob("serversJob", "MainGroup")
            .Build();

        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(serversJob, serversTrigger);

        await scheduler.Start();
    }

    public async void StopAsync()
    {
        // Some logic
    }
}
```

JobFactory.cs

```
public class JobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider Container;

    public JobFactory(IServiceProvider container)
    {
        this.Container = container;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return this.Container.GetService(bundle.JobDetail.JobType) as IJob;
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {
        var disposable = job as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Serversjob.cs

```
public readonly Settings settings;

public ServersJob(IOptionsSnapshot<Settings> options)
{
    settings = options.Value;
}

public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    int gameServerVersion = settings.GameServerVersion;
    return;
}
```

This works fine, but the job doesn't reflect any changes done. Am I missing the obvious (probably)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do i understand it correct that the Job isn't changing the value? Why is `Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)` from your `Serversjob` async? The job already runs in his own Thread/Task, there is no need to async it.

Comment: That is correct, the value doesn't change. I tested with a controller as advertised in the many examples on the web and it works fine. Just the job won't work with the updated value. And the task is `async`, as it contains a call to an `async` function. Does it make a difference?

Comment: ok, but your `Execution()` method doesn't show any async call. I would guess that Quartz can't handle async Tasks like you want it and i don't see any need for it. The Job is already executed in its own Thread/Task. Just remove `async Task` from your method definition. I guess that should solve your issue. If not, try to debug and observe that it really executes the change.

Comment: @Rabban I didn't provide the complete code for the `Execute()` function, the full version contains an HTML request and runs fine.

Comment: Did you removed `async Task` and tried it without it?

Comment: I'll try it out asap and let you know

Comment: @Rabban Doesn't make a difference, whether with or without `async`. I updated the `StartAsync` method, maybe I have a mistake in there somewhere.